# Male/female wire connectors - How to tell AWG/mm^2 rating?

Tags: wire

So I have a project where I will be running 20 AWG wires. Now there will be one section where I will need to connect the wires with a male/female connector.

I'm having trouble identifying which connectors should do the job safely, as I prioritise safety first.

How does one figure this out? When I type in "male female 2 pin connector" on Aliexpress I get a lot of results, but it's never stated for which wire gauges the connectors are for!

I also keep hearing about "pitch", i.e. "SM2.54 Kits 25 sets Kit in box 2p 3p 4p 2.54mm Pitch Female and Male Header Connectors Adaptor". In the example here "2.54mm pitch", what does that mean?

Comment: Try searching a more reputable distributor like digikey or mouser.

Comment: Try searching with current rating..

Comment: What do you mean "connect wires"? How many wires? Two? Usually there there is a requirement to observe polarity as well. So are you asking which connector is suitable to carry the current as a 20-AWG wire?

Comment: @Ale..chenski Let's just take one wire as an example. I need to be able to disconnect the wire in the middle (hence the male-female connector). However I don't know which connectors are suitable to a 20 AWG wire.

Comment: The scope of your question seems to be too broad to answer. Maybe you should start with Wikipedia, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_connector

Comment: @Hearth Ahh thanks. I suspected that this information should be given in the product specifications and digikey does this exactly. Oh well I guess I'll just have to find someone who states it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A search at Digikey brings up this 24-18 AWG connector set
https://www.digikey.com/products/en/kits/connector-kits/656?k=molex&k=&pkeyword=molex&sv=0&pv300=814&sf=1&FV=ffe00290&quantity=&ColumnSort=0&page=1&stock=1&pageSize=25

Answer (score 1):

A 20 AWG wire is rated for 5 A (see ["American Wire Gauge"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_wire_gauge)). Therefore you are looking for a connector with contact rating of 5 A sustained current or more.

You have many options. For a 2-pin (or 1-pin) connector you can pick an industrial-quality circular connector. It will be very safe and reliable, but it will cost you an arm and leg. Or you can pick a "one circuit" male pin and female receptacle with appropriate housing. BTW, if a connector has an "array" construction and more than one pin on a regular distance, this is called "pitch".

A good alternative to high-ampacity connectors has been developed in RC toy industry, primarily to connect batteries in toy boats/airplanes/cars/helicopters. They are coming in a naked form (various sizes of plugs/receptacles collectively referred as "banana" plugs), or have polarized and lockable housing. Here is an example from [Banggood.com](https://usa.banggood.com/AMASS-XT30U-Plug-2mm-Black-Female-Male-Banana-Plug-Connector-p-1208215.html):

[image]

Surprisingly, it comes with full specifications (15 A DC rating etc.), and engineering-quality drawings. There are individual contacts of this sort, and smaller ones.